# C++ FTP PORT command implementation using sockets

Tags: sockets, ftp, port

I am trying to implement active mode for my cpp ftp client.

I was trying to implement simple LISTEN server, netstat -ant said it is listening on 0.0.0.0:port (for example 1025).

In client when I send PORT 0,0,0,0,4,1\r\n server replies with code 500 - illegal port command.

What I should more to do to make it works? Thanks

**MOREINFO**

my server code:
 ..sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY; I can change to inaddr_any to only IP that is "running" e.g. filezilla is connected with server on 192.168.1.13 - when I use 192.168.1.13 as inet_addr("192.168.1.13") it **works** but how to set up new tcp listen ip? it returns BIND problem when I try for example 192.168.1.**14**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're listening at 0.0.0.0, which just means 'any', but the peer needs an actual IP address, not 0.0.0.0. You need to send it a public IP address that will reach your listening socket.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I have this in my code: is.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY, when I see how filezilla enters active mode there is always "192.168.x.x". So how can I set up server that listens on public ip? thanks

Comment: You don't have to change anything about your server setup. INADDR_ANY is perfect for that part of it. You just have to tell the peer something it can use, in the PORT message. You can't connect to 0.0.0.0, so it isn't useful, or correct.

Comment: OK, SO how I know what IP put to PORT command? On my ubuntu works for example 192.168.1.13, but it wont work on each system I think. Thanks

Comment: Well it depends what the system's public IP address is. You can enumerate its own IP addresses, but if you're behind a firewall or port forwarder of any description that has its own IP address you'll have to provide it via configuration.

Comment: Ok. Just one more question about active upload. Only thing I must do is send data to socket of my server? (it looks like i would send data from me to me) - will ftp read data from that socket and will auto-upload it? thanks

Comment: Yep. See the RFC. It will ask for a file on the command port , then you reply OK if you can send it, then you send it via the next connection from the same IP address on the data port.